# Github Enterprise - automaticlly token renewal

Tags: github, token, renewal

Is it possible in Github Enterprise to make a script that will automatically renew a token on expiration date ?
I am using Python but i've not find a documentation for this.
My scope here is to integrate it into a CICD cycle and not bother with manual token renewal !